# Does Android supports In-App payment mode through PayPal?

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase, google-checkout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How integrate Paypal in android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631841/how-integrate-paypal-in-android-application)

does android supports In-App payment through PayPal or we need to go with Google Checkout.
Can anyone please help me with this.....

Comment: possible double: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631841/how-integrate-paypal-in-android-application

Comment: May this helps you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787738/paypal-as-in-app-payment-model-in-android

Comment: hi, while executing sample code given by PayPal getting error. it is loading and on screen it is showing as "Initializing " & after some time giving message as "failure . Could not initialize the paypal library". can you help me with this......

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two points to note:

1. PayPal has an [in-app payment system which will work on Android](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/mobile-payment-libraries).
2. Google Market will ***not*** allow in-app payments [which aren't Google Checkout](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html).

So, you can add in-app payment using PayPal as long as you don't distribute the app via Google Play.

Comment: hi Terence Eden, actually i did not understand what you are saying about "don't distribute the app via Google Play".The doubt raised for me is, if we register our in android market means i think it will get distributed via Google play. then is it safe to use Paypal in my app or not.... Actually i am new to android. so i am in a dilemma about this.

Comment: No, you cannot distribute the app through Google Play. You can distribute it yourself or in other stores.

Comment: To update the 2. Part of the Answer: there are two exceptions: 1 products which are also hardware (cinema tickets) and 2 digital products which are also available and usable OUTSIDE of the app http://play.google.com/intl/ALL_de/about/developer-content-policy.html#showlanguages

Comment: Hi @TerenceEden, are there any markets we can distribute the payment-selfmade apps through?3Q!

Comment: @TerenceEden then why Paypal Android SDK exists?

Comment: Because you can distribute Android apps via many different stores. You are not restricted to Google Play. You can also distribute your apps independently.

Comment: Article of May 2014: http://www.theverge.com/2014/5/15/5721192/google-play-store-android-paypal-integration

Comment: @patrics: Are these exception how Skype or Spotify sell in-app purchases (i.e. Skype credit) because this credit can also be used outside of Android app?

Comment: @MSquare yes, as far as i know: the products can be used outside the google/android ecosystem and therefore can be purchased with other systems

Answer (score 1):

yes, Android Supports in Application purchase through Paypal.I have Done it in my application.

First U have to make Test account on Paypal Sandbox. using that you can test your application perfectly working or not. after testing you can add your Live Application ID in to your source code. if you need I can give my source code.

Comment: Hi Bhavesh,could you please provide source code out here.So that all of us can use and learn.Further,you mean we can integrate paypal libraries on our app,and we can make it available on playstore

Comment: @laaptu did u got any solution for this?

Comment: @Nishant: yes it is possible,I have recently uploaded an application that uses PayPal purchase ,you can find the functionality on video upload process on audition section. [Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.britasiasuperstar)

Comment: @Bhavesh can you please share your source code?

Comment: I am really confused as to PayPal integration into an Android app and distribution through Google Play. Google's agreement states: " All fees received by Developers for Products distributed via the Market must be processed by the Market's Payment Processor.". And Google supports PayPal as a payment processor??? Something smells fishy here. http://play.google.com/intl/ALL_us/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

Comment: Does Google Play support PaylPal integration app?

Comment: As of May 2014, PayPal is supported: http://www.theverge.com/2014/5/15/5721192/google-play-store-android-paypal-integration

Comment: That link http://www.theverge.com/2014/5/15/5721192/google-play-store-android-paypal-integration seems to suggest that Google Billing will provide PayPal as one of the payment options - NOT that you developer can directly integrate with PayPal SDK for billing.