# Android In-app Purchase Fees

Tags: android

I am integrating in-app purchase into my application but I have a few questions that I have not been able to find answer to.

Can anyone tell me what are the fees that google applies per transaction for selling digital content thru in app purchase using google payment flow?

Answer (score 1):

30% charge as a standard :) [Google Fee's](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153481?hl=en) Specifically:

> In-app billing is available to developers in supported locations for merchants. In-app billing may only be applied to digital goods sold inside applications distributed through Google Play. The Google Play program policies apply to in-app transactions. The standard 30% transaction fee applies to in-app transactions on Google Play.

Comment: That means everything that I sell thru my app will get a 30% fee? That is a lot.

Comment: Well it's all relative and they do provide the massive infrastructure to host your app and process the payment for you. I don't think it's that bad a deal to be honest.

Comment: Is is possible to install Paypal as an alternative to avoid the fees, really 30% in every transaction is a lot of money.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is a PayPal api for use with Android and in-app purchases. However, I also believe that you can't publish via Google Play if you're not using Google Checkout. I may be wrong though. I'm sure if you search on here there are a few questions on the subject

It's all much for muchness though. If you weren't using Google, you'd have to publish yourself. Google themselves are only acting as the publisher and (as it is with most software development) the publisher always takes a cut.

Comment: Here is one very question, confirming what I thought: [does-android-supports-in-app-payment-mode-through-paypal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632130/does-android-supports-in-app-payment-mode-through-paypal)

Comment: Thank you Yizz!! for the quick response