# Android subscription without Google Play handle payment process

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, subscription, android-billing

Is it possible to build an Android app subscription system without link to Google Play in app billing? If using Google Play in app billing, Google Play will charge 30% of the transaction fee. If it is possible to implement the app subscription without link to Google Play,anyone has good tutorial for that? Thanks!

Comment: i myself am looking for a different answer to this. There are android devices that cannot have google play/services on, so that means google APIs for in app purchases will not work, so how would one overcome this? I'd like to use in app purchases without requiring google services on the device to reach as many people as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use, for example, the paypal api, but you wont be able to publish it to the play store.

> Developers charging for apps and downloads from Google Play must do so by using Google Play's payment system. In-app purchases: Developers offering virtual goods or currencies within a game downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment. Developers offering additional content, services or functionality within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment, except: where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g., buying movie tickets, or buying a publication where the price also includes a hard copy subscription); or where payment is for digital content or goods that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g., buying songs that can be played on other music players).

Source: [Are there alternatives to using Google's in-app-billing , as a way to avoid publishing private info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929139/are-there-alternatives-to-using-googles-in-app-billing-as-a-way-to-avoid-publ)